# Find a vector that spans the given set

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, vectors, span

- Question in book:

Let H be the set of all vectors of the form [-2t, 5t, 3t]. Find a vector **v** in R3 such that H=Span{**v**}.  Why does this show that H is a subspace of R3?

- Answer from solution manual: The set H=Span{**v**}, where **v**=[1,3,2].  Thus H is a subspace of R3 by Theorem 1*.
- My question:  I know this is stupid but I don't see where the answer **v**=[1,3,2] comes from.  I answered this question as [-2,5,3].  If someone would give explanation as to how this answer came about, I'd be very appreciative!

*Theorem 1: If **v_1**,…,**v_p** are in vector space V, then Span{**v_1**,…,**v_p**} is a subspace of V.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the correct answer is $v=[-2,5,3]$ so then $Span{(v)}=Span{([-2,5,3])}=H$. Because $v\subset \mathbb{R}^3$ so $H$ is a subspace of $\mathbb{R}^3$.

Answer (score 1):

You're answer is correct. From the definition of "span" a base from H would be [-2,5,3]. [1,3,2] is not even a vector from H.

Comment: I'm afraid I don't see how we got [1,3,2]

Comment: -2,5,3 is a vector from H. I think the answer 1,3,2 is incorrect. How do we get -2,5,3 from 1,3,2?

Comment: It's the exact contrary! $[1,2,3]\notin H$, while $[-2,5,3]\in H$.

Comment: Sorry, my mistake. I've edited the answer.

Comment: Thanks all for your input!